# Fork não restaura as variáveis

Tags: c

A idéia do código é:
Dar fork 3 vezes,ou seja, a partir do pai criar três filhos(com count=0,count=1 e count=2).
Os filhos então,ao voltar do loop vão ver que seu i==0 e vão sair do loop.
Ao entrar na outra condição,eles(os filhos,pois i==0),ao printar o count deveria aparecer **0,1,2**,mas está aparecendo **0,0,0**,depois dar um exec passando:
1-o caminho com o nome do executável.
2-Qual o número do filho(0,1,2).

Tenho o programa pai:...

```
 i = 1;
for( count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
        if( i != 0 ) {
            i = fork();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if( i == 0 ) {
        printf("%d",count);
        char arg[10];
        sprintf(arg, "%d", count);
        execl("/home/Downloads/filho",arg,NULL);
```

....
O meu ouuput do printf esperado era:

> 0,1,2

Mas está saindo:

> 0,0,0

EDIT-----
Talvez no filho eu estou pegando o valor de maneira errada:
Eu estou passando assim:

```
char arg[10];
            sprintf(arg, "%d", count);
            execl("/home/Downloads/filho",arg,NULL);
```

E no executavel filho:

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Porém dessa forma ele gera um problema que não aparece nenhum resultado no executavel filho.
e caso coloco assim:

```
int n = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Ele printa os resultados do executavel filho,mas de maneira errada.

filho.c:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        int n = atoi(argv[2]);

        printf("Filho #%d,n); 
    exit(0);
}
```

Output esperado:

> Filho #1 Filho #2 Filho #3

Output quando sai:

> Filho #0 Filho #0 Filho #0

Comment: Como você definiu `i`?

Comment: Só com este trecho fica difícil entender o que está acontecendo. E como ele parece ser fazer muito esquisito, seria bom dizer qual é o propósito dele.

Comment: i está inicializado com 1;A idéia é dar um execl no processo filho,passando como parâmetro o valor do loop em que foi dado o fork.Por exemplo:no primeiro loop count=0 então queria passar arg=0 e assim por diante

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @bigown Editado

Comment: Pelo trecho postado, não consigo entender o que está acontecendo. Cada filho vai tentar o `fork`, fazer `i` virar `0` e então sair do loop - com `count` igual a `1`. A saída então deveria ser `1,1,1`, e não `0,0,0`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Expliquei o que eu acho que o código deveria fazer.

Comment: @felipealves Desculpe, ignorância minha, o `fork` [não funciona como eu achava que funcionava...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11288226/520779) Ainda assim, a saída esperada deveria ser `1,2,3` - e não `0,1,2` - pois o `count` de cada processo filho é incrementado pelo menos uma vez.

Comment: OK,era isso mesmo,1,2,3 erro meu também,enfim,não funciona :/

Comment: Esta faltando uma chave no ultimo if?

Comment: [Experimentei no ideone](http://ideone.com/UwuHNp) e o resultado foi como o esperado (fora de ordem, é claro). O problema deve estar em algum outro lugar...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Editei com outro possível problema

Comment: Uma coisa de cada vez... O seu resultado no processo filho está consistente com o que está acontecendo com o `count`. Se esse problema for resolvido, creio que o filho vai funcionar corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Tu não estás a passar o `argv[1]` para o filho

```
execl("/home/Downloads/filho", arg, NULL); // NULL vai para argv[1]
//    path                     argv[0]
```

devia ser

```
execl("/home/Downloads/filho", "nome do filho", arg, NULL); // NULL vai para argv[2]
//    path                     argv[0]          argv[1]
```